# Order on eigenvalues on diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If the eigenvalues are say $-1$, $-1$ and $2$ for a $3$ x $3$ matrix, then when comes to the diagonal matrix, is it (from top left, to bottom right) $-1$ $-1$ $2$ or $2$ $-1$ $-1$ or $-1$ $2$ $-1$? Does the order matter? How do you know what the order is?

Comment: This is simply you choice of basis. there is no "right" or "wrong" order. Remember the choice of basis is up to you.

Comment: But would it ever be the possibility of the order of $P^{-1}AP$ have a different order to the one you choose?

Comment: You may order as you wish according how you order the eigenvectors in the transition matrix.  So just permute the columns of $P$ to get a different order

Comment: You have to put the eigenvectors into $P$ in the order matching the eigenvalues on the diagonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter, it just has to be coherent with the order of the columns of $P$ in $A=PDP^{-1}$.
In some applications we prefer to order the eigenvalues but in theory it's not necessary.